# Adding a view defined in XML via addContentView

Tags: android, android-view

I'm using addContentView to add a child view to my main view like this:

```
    TableLayout.LayoutParams tlp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_NAME);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    addContentView(textView,tlp);
```

Rather than defining the view programmatically like I do above, can I define the view in an xml file and then add it via addContentView?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate more about your question.

Comment: I rephrased the question.  thanks!

Comment: Not sure about your use case, but it looks like you might be able to achieve what you want using fragments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can I define the view in an xml file and then add it via
>   addContentView?

Yes, first inflate xml file using [LayoutInflater](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)  which return a `View`. pass View to `addContentView` after setting layout `LayoutParams`

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View view;
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xml_file_name, null);
//.. add LayoutParams to view

// call addContentView
addContentView(view,tlp);
```

Comment: Better use the parent view instead of `null`.

Comment: What is 'tlp' ?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use something like

```
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.your_xml_layout_file, this);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can load a view from xml using LayoutInflater:

```
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.file, rootView, false);
```